# unused import statement in android studio and import is colored gray

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android and I can't seemed to figure out what causes this error.

Im trying to experiment a text view or edit view where if you click the button, it will save the inputted text and display it on the text view once you return to the app.

The error prompt `error: cannot find symbol variable textView` and sometimes even `error: cannot find symbol variable Connect`.

**Question:**

why is it that `textView` got error even if I imported `import android.widget.TextView;`

Also, why is the `import android.widget.TextView;` is colored light gray?

below are the screenshots:
[Import color to gray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ar0gS.jpg) and 
[Compiler error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQ5Y7.jpg)

Here is my code

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText textView;
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    final SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Connect.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String oldItem = sharedPref.getString("oldItem", "Nothing created yet...");

    textView.setText(oldItem);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putString("oldItem", textView.getText().toString());
            editor.commit();
        }
    });
}
}
```

**Update:**

I din't add any ID on my EditText XML code thats why the machine cannot find it.

```
android:id="@+id/textView"
```

Also, I updated from this

```
final SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Connect.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

to this

```
final SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

I'm not really sure what's the difference between Connect and Context.

Thanks to @Kapil G

Comment: your compiler error is unrelated to the fact that the import is gray.

Comment: TextView is never use in you activity that is why it turns gray, you use `EditText` with a variable name `textView` which causes your confusion

Comment: plz add your xml code, i think view id might be different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check you XML file to see if you have declared `R.id.textView` as TextView or Edittext.

Both are different. Your input field is your EditText and your output field where you want to show the data is TextView.

also not sure what you have declared as Connect. but `SharedPreference` need the mode from a Context so your line should be like this -

```
final SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Plus your import is coming as gray because you have not used TextView component anywhere in the activity.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't add any id on the xml. Here is the new id of edit text android:id="@+id/textView". Also I revert my original code on the main activity and updated the shared preferences from your code. This works but I'm not really sure what's the difference between Connect and Context.

Comment: @Andy not sure what is Connect that you were using. There is not something called Connect that provides a mode for sharedpreference.

Comment: Me too! but that will be my homework or it will be answered later on my journey of learning android development. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Problem is: You are not using TextView.

```
textView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

=>

```
textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

Yes, EditText is a kind of TextView, but it seems that in your xml, it will be TextView. So, how about cast to TextView ?

Comment: Thanks! I got the answer on the second question but I got 2 more errors when I implemented your answer. Error: cannot find symbol variable textView | error: incompatible types: TextView cannot be converted to EditText | error: cannot find symbol variable Connect. I clean it before rebuilding it.

Answer (score 0):

It is simply nothing but unused.
If you think you need it keep it or else you can remove it.
Also most of the time imports are brought automatically so you dont have to worry.

If you want to bring imports simply just do:

```
Alt + Enter
```